# JQuery droppable() does not recognize "this" object reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, droppable

I have an Object like this:

```
function ImageHolder(Attributes, Parent)
{
    this.Id = Attributes['Id'];
    this.Parent = Parent;

    this.Element = $('<div/>');

        this.msg = "hello world";

    this.Parent.append(this.Element);


    this.handleDrop = function(e, ui)
    {
        alert(this.msg);

    };

    this.Element.droppable({drop: this.handleDrop});
}
```

I then create an object like this:

```
holder = new ImageHolder(A,B);
```

But when I try and drop something onto the Element, I get this error:

```
this.msg is undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of this;

```
var thisCopy = this;
```

before the following function, then replace like so...

```
this.handleDrop = function(e, ui)
{
    alert(thisCopy.msg);

};
```

Comment: `this` within the handleDrop function is referring to the handleDrop function itself and not the object outside it. Also, `thisCopy` (which you can name whatever you like) is a shallow copy so it will not conflict with other objects on the same page, and will update the real `this` at the same time. So you can use `thisCopy` anywhere in your object.